# IP Address Find and Replace using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

How do I create the function to find and replace an IP address in a string?  I can easily find and replace the text, but the IP's are giving me a fit.  Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text File Changer v1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
function findaNamendReplaceAll() {    var findaCIP = "192.168.0.4";
var replaceaCIP = document.myInput.replaceWithCIP.value;
var tmp = fulltexta.replace(findaCIP/gi,replaceaCIP); 
document.myInput.fulltext.value = tmp;
*/  

document.myInput.fulltext.value = fulltexta.replace(findaCIP/gi,replaceaCIP);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Text" onsubmit="return false">
<h1>Configuration Tool</h1>
New IP: <input type="text" id="replaceWithCIP" name="replaceWithCIP" value="">
<br><br>
<button onclick="findaNamendReplaceAll()">BUILD</button>
<br><br>

<textarea id="fulltext" name="fulltext" rows="20" cols="100">
IPADDR=192.168.0.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fulltext').value = ''">Clear</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fulltext').value = str">Restore</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to support IPv6 as well?

Comment: You'll want to find a regular expression that matches an IP address.  I'm not putting one here, because you will find many resources both here and on google for that regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use RegEx to match the string. Here is an example. The RegEx pattern I used is from http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

```
var ipPattern = /\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/g;

var realIp = "123.212.6.1";
var fakeIp = "627.192.388.299";

console.log("Real IP is real? " + ipPattern.test(realIp));
console.log("Fake IP is fake? " + !ipPattern.test(fakeIp));
```